# помогите с прокруткой recyclerview

Tags: java, android

Хочу реализовать в ленте такую штуку: когда пролистываешь на пару новостей recyclerview, то появлялась кнопка ВВЕРХ (поднять ленту вверх в самое начало).

как сделать кнопку знаю, а вот какую проверку поставить на recyclerview незнаю!!! неподскажите?

Comment: как вариант через OnScrollListener

Comment: а там какую проверку посставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                                if (dy > 0) {
                                    buttontop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                if (dy < 0){
                                    buttontop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```